# Insert and select in one row sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to insert some values in the table.

I can do it easily using the query(from php):

```
mysql_query('INSERT  INTO `TABLE1`(`user_id`,`value1`,`date`) VALUES("'.$user_id.'",".$value1.",".time().")');
```

But this time I do not have variable $user_id. I only have the username. So I need to do one more query to USERS dataase to get `user_id` from row where `username` is equal to my variable.

Is it possible not to do 2 queries? I meen INSERT and SELECT in one query?

P.S. I know that mysql_query function is depreciated. I used it here jusst for example.

Comment: have a look at `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Comment: define a user id in case statment and exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nested subquery:

```
INSERT  INTO `TABLE1`
    (`user_id`,`value1`,`date`)
VALUES
    (
        (
             SELECT
                 `user_id`
             FROM
                 `user`
             WHERE
                 `username` = 'your-user-name' // should be unique in order to work
        ),
        'value1',
        NOW()
    );
```

Comment: you are really faster, I see your answer just before I post it.

Comment: @RamSharma I'm just refreshing too often. `(:`

Answer (score 1):

The following query may be what you're looking for but it may be better to first get the user_id and then proceed the insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (user_id, value1, date)
SELECT MAX(user_id) + 1 -- If the user_id is an numeric value...
    ,'user-name-here'
    ,NOW()
FROM TABLE1
```

With this query i'm getting the last user_id from the table and i increment it by 1 in order to insert the new user in the table.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank yoou very much! :) It's useful method!

Comment: This method is faster than a subquery